# Keycloak OpenID .well-known/ endpoints security issue

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

I use Keycloak with OpenID and I am wondering how to disable or remove well-known endpoints like:
`...well-known/openid-configuration`
 `...well-known/uma2-configuration`
and
`...protocol/openid-connect/certs`

mentioned endpoints are available which is not good in terms of security in my system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clients and API usually needs to be able to access these endpoints to for example configure them selves and also to download the public signing keys.

They don't contain any private information and even companies like Google exposes their own document here
https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

So, I wouldn't be to worry about that.

Comment: ok, thank you :) anyway do you know if it can be turned off somehow?

Comment: as I can see https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/uma2-configuration is hidden

Comment: But perhaps uma2-configuration is not supported by Google? not every auth server provides all the endpoints...

Comment: you are right, I agree with /.wel-known/ endpoints, but what do you think about other endpoints

https://{host}:{port}/auth/realms/realm_name/protocol/openid-connect/certs or https://{host}:{port}/auth/realms/realm_name

there is a lot of informations about certificates and keys, x5t and so one

Comment: It is up to the auth server, what features they actually supports and provides, you never exposes private keys through these endpoints, only the public key part/certificates and those are safe to share with anyone.

Comment: Is any way to disable in openid or keycloak configuration mentioned endpoints? I am forcing it that because it may be require in my project and I coudln't find it on the internet but many peoples ask for same without clear answer

Comment: i think it depends if you have public clients like mobile clients that needs to authenticate with your auth server, they might need public access to it. Otherwise you can just block it in your firewall and use it just internally. With tokens your internal services usually needs access to these endpoints to function. or you have to provide the public keys manually

Comment: in my case all endpoints are available only by https and in internal network

Comment: @DevoPsky you got the solution for this issue. I am in same issue wanted to disable or limit the information exposed by these endpoints